# Java os path operations, joins, and moving up levels

Tags: java

I have 2 related questions regarding files, and the File class in Java.

I gather the best practice way to build a path - and have it OS agnostic - is like this:

```
File file = new File("dir" + File.separator + "filename.ext");
```

My first question is, "Is there a Java equivalent of python os.path.join function built into Java?"
i.e. Is there a function where I can do something like this:

```
String path = some_func("arbitrary", "number", "of", "subdirs", "filename.ext");
```

I suspect if such a thing exists, I may need to pass an Array of Strings to the function, rather than an arbitrary number of args, but the above would be ideal.

But regardless of the answer to the question above, my second question is, "is there a built in way to move a level up when specifying a path?"

i.e. Is the correct way, to do something like this:

```
String rel_path = ".." + File.separator + "filename.ext";
```

Or is there something like this:

```
String rel_path = File.level_up + File.separator + "filename.ext";
```

Cheers all!

Comment: `File.level_up` -> `".."`

Comment: [Paths.get("..", "dir2", ..., "filename.ext"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html). Though in praxis `/` works on Windows too.

Answer (score 2):

> I gather the best practice way to build a path - and have it OS agnostic - is like this:
>
> ```
> File file = new File("dir" + File.separator + "filename.ext");
> ```

Or like this (see the API documentation on the constructors of `java.io.File`):

```
File file = new File("dir", "filename.ext");
```

Note that this takes only two parameters - the name of the parent directory and the filename (not an arbitrary list of subdirectories).

You're looking for `java.nio.file.Paths.get()`:

```
Path path = Paths.get("arbitrary", "number", "of", "subdirs", "filename.ext");
```

Note that gives you a `Path` rather than a `File`, if you really need a `File` then call `toFile()` on the `Path`.

Note: This is all new stuff in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of for Java 6, but you could use Apache's StringUtils to achieve the same effect:

[`StringUtils.join(components, File.separator)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29)

As above, where `components` is an `Iterable` or an array of your file path components.

e.g. `String path = StringUtils.join(new String[] {"foo", "bar"}, File.separator);`

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, Jesper is right imo that java.nio.Pages.get() is best if you're using java 7.

On the second part of your question, consider using:

```
file.getParentFile().getName();
```

To navigate to the parent of the given file (or dir).